# Is there a way to make a OneToOne field list editable in Django admin?

Tags: python, django

In a particular Django setup, there is a model (call it item foo) with a OneToOne relationship to another model (call it bar). Is there a way to make a particular field in 'bar' list_editable?

List editable is where it appears in the django admin list view as an editable field for each item in the list, so updates to many items can be made.

Example:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(....)

class Bar(models.Model):
  foo = models.OneToOneField(Foo)
 other_bit = models.BootleanField(default=False)
```

Then in admin what I would like to do (this won't work) is something like:

```
class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  fields = ('name', )
  list_display = ('name', 'bar__otherbit')
  list_editable = ('name', 'bar__otherbit')
```

Is there a way to make list editable work here?

Comment: I'm not sure about editing, but you surely can display the fields of Bar in Foo admin

Comment: I have displaying them done by adding fairly simple admin method.

Comment: did you find the solution?